# Is there a faster way to loop through files in a folder?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have a bunch of excel files and i want to loop through and extract all data from them in the quickest way possible. I feel like my solution is too slow! It takes around 5 seconds between each sheet which is too slow! Any ideas on how to improve this?

```
Location = 'C:/Users/Public/Documents/'
Path = os.listdir(Location)
for x in Path:
    if x.endswith(".xlsm"):
        a = pd.read_excel(Location + str(x), sheet_name='a', header=0, dtype = str)
        b = pd.read_excel(Location + str(x), sheet_name='b', header=0, dtype=str)
        c = pd.read_excel(Location + str(x), sheet_name='c', header=0, dtype=str)
        d = pd.read_excel(Location + str(x), sheet_name='d', header=0, dtype=str)
```

Comment: use `glob.glob(*.xlsm)`

Comment: also, your indentation is wrong.